# Pandas Yahoo Finance: AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tesla

I am getting this error: AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'tz_localize' when i try to use the history function... Please have a look
[image]

Comment: [ask] specifically says *not* to use screenshots of code / data /errors.

Comment: Not a DatetimeIndex? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_localize.html

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the issue with [`0.2.18`](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/releases/tag/0.2.18) (*latest*) :

```
import yfinance as yf

tesla_stk = yf.Ticker("TSLA")

teslta_data = tesla_stk.history(period="max")
```

Output :

```
print(teslta_data)

                  Open   High    Low  Close     Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits
Date                                                                           
2010-06-29 0...   1.27   1.67   1.17   1.59  281494500       0.00          0.00
2010-06-30 0...   1.72   2.03   1.55   1.59  257806500       0.00          0.00
2010-07-01 0...   1.67   1.73   1.35   1.46  123282000       0.00          0.00
...                ...    ...    ...    ...        ...        ...           ...
2023-05-15 0... 167.66 169.76 164.55 166.35  105592500       0.00          0.00
2023-05-16 0... 165.65 169.52 164.35 166.52   96839500       0.00          0.00
2023-05-17 0... 168.41 173.99 167.19 173.11   83557527       0.00          0.00
```

You might just need to *upgrade* `yfinance` or *install* it from GitHub (see [*GH1332*](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/1332) & [*GH1080*](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/discussions/1080)).